# Segmenting question

Tags: usage, word

Should 飽飽 and 小朋友们 be treated as single words in

```
山羊喜欢青草，
肚子饱饱才回家。
小朋友们别学它，
努力做个好宝宝。
```

?

Segmenting software that I use splits 飽飽 and separates 们.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

飽飽 and 小朋友们 should be treated as single words, but the segmenting is reasonable

飽 (full) and 小朋友(child/children) are single words. 飽飽(really full) is a modified form of 飽; 小朋友们(the children) is a modified form of 小朋友, so yes, you can treat them as single words, The segmenting software just separated the modification elements '**reduplication**' and '**plural suffix**' from the general word **飽** and **小朋友**

I think it does that to finely segment the word itself, not just segmenting the sentence into words and clauses.

- 飽飽 is [reduplication](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Reduplication_of_adjectives) of 飽
- 小朋友们 is general term 小朋友(child/ children) followed by plural suffix 们 which indicate plural

> 們 https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%80%91
>
> Suffix indicating plural for pronouns, some animated nouns and personifications.
>
> ```
>    我們 / 我们  ―  wǒmen  ―  we
>     孩子們 / 孩子们  ―  háizimen  ―  children
> ```

Comment: Do you mean "should be"?  You call it a "suffix" but say it should be a separate word?

Comment: 飽 (full) and 小朋友(child/children) are single words, 飽飽(really full) is a modified form of 飽; 小朋友们(the children) is a modified form of 小朋友, so yes, you can treat them as single words, The segmenting software just separated the modification elements from the general word

Comment: ?? I don't see the word "edit" but I somehow read it differently before.  Makes sense as currently written, although I think the segmentation is an error in that each _can_ be a separate word, but in these examples they are not.  Segmentation AFAIK can't consider meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't your dictionary also mention, 'machine segmenting is never 100% accurate'?? If it doesn't, remember that anyway!

山羊喜欢青草， goats like new grass,
肚子饱饱才回家。 only go home when their bellies are full,
小朋友们别学它， little friends don't be a goat,
努力做个好宝宝。 try hard to be a little darling.

Comment: If I thought machine segmenting was 100% accurate, I wouldn't have asked if it were wrong.  But I appreciate the translation—it's slightly better than the one I came up with.